# Multiplayer Game : web-based

Tags: node.js, gwt, jquery, web-applications, multiplayer

Need a little suggestion for my game framework web-application. The games interaction would be more of similar to what is there in "mafia wars( zynga )", but with very less things to interact with ... The player merely would have to click to trigger an event and wait for the response, and then proceed for the next task...

The games I need to implement are mainly for the human behaviour studies... based on game theory ( "prisoners dilemma" / "chicken Game"/ Row-column based games )

The key things to keep in mind are as follows.

- Not more then 20 users at any instance.
- No Heavy Graphics / animation required.
- Framework should be expandable to add to new similar games
- There should be no latency issues, and in no circumstance the server
  should become unresponsive due to client requests.

The Alternatives for the framework I am thinking are

- Jquery ( ajax + UI ) + HTML + JAVA
- HTML5 + node.js + JAVA
- GWT ( Google Web Toolkit ) + JAVA

Please let me know if there are some other better alternatives or not ...

Currently I have created a prototype application based on Jquery ... I am yet working on n/w and multiplayer configuration... My main concern is how can I effectively display the other users state without latency issues.. Is there an existing framework which I can leverage ?

--- Pranav

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) w/ [socket.io](http://socket.io/) on the server side. You could keep your HTML5 / jQuery solution for the frontend and just add the socket stuff.

Check out this tutorial on a multiroom chat app. Should be pretty close to what you need for a multiplayer game:
http://psitsmike.com/2011/10/node-js-and-socket-io-multiroom-chat-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the link ... :)
I would try it out and see if this works out for me ...

Answer (score 0):

You wouldnt need JAVA in addition to nodejs and HTML/CSS. nodejs would handle more requests that the other options and is more suited to real time bi directional communication between clients and / or servers. Ideal for a multiplayer game.

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout Google's [playn](http://code.google.com/p/playn/). 
It is a is a cross-platform game abstraction library for writing games that compile to:

- Desktop Java
- HTML5 Browsers
- Android
- iOS
- Flash

AFAIK Angry Birds for the Chrome Web Store was written using this framework.